# Youtube video.js plugin

Tags: video.js

I installed the youtube plugin for video.js and I am having an issue with the latest version.

The problem is youtube videos don't seem to work.

Here is the code to my websites head. What can I do to fix this? (yes I have used the search but nothing seems to work)

```
<link href="http://www.randomness-videos.cu.cc/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://www.randomness-videos.cu.cc/video.js"></script>

<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://www.randomness-videos.cu.cc/video-js.swf"
</script>
```

my video code is this below

```
<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls 
           preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" width="640" height="360" 
           data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ" }'>
    </video>
```